# HTTPS auth on Android

Tags: java, android, https, authorization

I have some code for HTTP auth for Android. But it doesn't work for https auth. How can I re-factor code under https authorization ?

Code for HTTP auth below:

```
HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(HOST);
String credentials = login + ":" + mPassword;
authString = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("auth", authString);
editor.apply();
request.addHeader("Authorization", authString);
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

int result = 0;
try {
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
    result = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
} catch (Exception e) {
    result = -1;
}
return result;
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is never a good enough error description. please extend it, for example with an error message or stack trace.

Comment: It's freezing on line with: HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, using custom ssl socket factory and creating HTTP client with params.

CustomSSLSocketFactory:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

public class CustomSSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory{
      SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
      /**
       * Generate Certificate for ssl connection
       * @param truststore
       * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
       * @throws KeyManagementException
       * @throws KeyStoreException
       * @throws UnrecoverableKeyException
       */
      public CustomSSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore)
                  throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException,
                  KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
            super(truststore);
            TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager(){
                  @Override
                  public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
                              throws CertificateException {
                  }
                  @Override
                  public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                              String authType) throws CertificateException {
                  }
                  @Override
                  public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return null;
                  }
            };
            sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] {tm}, null);
      }

      @Override
      public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port,
                  boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
            return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port,
                        autoClose);
      }

      @Override
      public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
            return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
      }
}
```

End util for creating HTTP client:

```
import java.security.KeyStore;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;

public class HTTPUtils {
      /**
       * HttpClient
       * @param isHTTPS
       * @return
       */
      public static HttpClient getNewHttpClient(boolean isHTTPS) {
            try {
                  if(!isHTTPS){
                        return getNewHttpClient();
                  }
                  KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
                  trustStore.load(null, null);
                  SSLSocketFactory sf = new CustomSSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
                  sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

                  HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
                  SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
                  registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

                  ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);
                  return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                  return null;
            }
      }
      /**
       * HttpClient for http request
       * @return
       */
      private static HttpClient getNewHttpClient(){
            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            return new DefaultHttpClient(params);
      }
}
```

Example:

```
String credentials = login + ":" + mPassword;
            authString = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
            HttpClient httpclient = HTTPUtils.getNewHttpClient(HOST.startsWith(HTTPS_STRING));
            URI newURI = URI.create(HOST);
            HttpGet httpGet =  new HttpGet(newURI);
            httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", authString);

            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
                int code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                return code;
...
```

Comment: Posting links as answer are not recommended as these answer becomes obsolete if link goes down/dead. I would suggest you to add how you solved in elaborated form. So that any user who gets to this page will get everything in this page only. Plus you will get up-votes too for writing good answer.

Answer (score 0):

> The default behaviour of HttpClient is suitable for most uses, however
> there are some aspects which you may want to configure. The most
> common requirements for customizing SSL are:
>
> 1. Ability to accept self-signed or untrusted SSL certificates. This is highlighted by an SSLException with the message Unrecognized SSL
>    handshake (or similar) being thrown when a connection attempt is made.
> 2. You want to use a third party SSL library instead of Sun's default implementation.

You may need an implementation of a custom protocol:

```
Protocol myhttps = new Protocol("https", new MySSLSocketFactory(), 443);
Protocol.registerProtocol("https", 
new Protocol("https", new MySSLSocketFactory(), 443));
HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
GetMethod httpget = new GetMethod("https://www.whatever.com/");
try {
  httpclient.executeMethod(httpget);
  System.out.println(httpget.getStatusLine());
} finally {
  httpget.releaseConnection();
}
```

`MySSLSocketFactory` is a custom socket factory that implements `org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SecureProtocolSocketFactory` interface
You can reference this link:[MySSLSocketFactory.java](https://github.com/mozilla/caseconductor-platform/blob/master/utest-webservice/utest-webservice-client/src/main/java/com/utest/webservice/client/rest/MySSLSocketFactory.java)

Comment: What is MySSLSocketFactory ?

Comment: @OkadzakiTomoe .. pleae check, I have updated the aswer

Comment: I don't understand your answer. What is Protocol object ?

Comment: @OkadzakiTomoe  sorry, You may need to add apache http net library to your project.

Comment: @OkadzakiTomoe .. The link you posted as answer in actually doing what is suggested(creating a custom ssl socket) however in an andorid context. Anyway, glad you solved it.